# One-tap login g_state cookie is not parseable on http.cookies SimpleCookie

Tags: python, cookies, request, google-signin, google-one-tap

I'm trying to integrate Google One-Tap login on our website. For backend, I am using a tornado server that uses http library to parse the Cookie header and setting it. More info about `tornado` cookie handling [here](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html). Basically Google One-Tap login adds this `g_state` cookie to set the user status on how they interact with the One-Tap modal ([source](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/subdomains)), and it's a behavior that we cannot change without altering the functionality of the plugin.

Now for some reason, when I call `self.cookies` inside the tornado request handler, it's returning empty even though `Cookie` header is set. The cookie header looks like this:

```
Cookie: g_state={"i_l":0}; token="abcde"
```

For some reason it didnt parse the cookie header properly. Dug up some code for parsing the cookies that tornado is using, and tried different ways to investigate it:

```
>>> from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
>>> token = 'g_state={"i_l":0};token="abcde"'
>>> dd = SimpleCookie()
>>> dd.load(token)
>>> dd
<SimpleCookie: >

# now try to rearranged the g_state to appear after token
>>> token2 = 'token="abcde";g_state={"i_l":0}'
>>> dd = SimpleCookie()
>>> dd.load(token2)
>>> dd
<SimpleCookie: token='abcde'>

# added sample token after it to check if it parses the cookies after g_state
>>> token2 = 'token="abcde";g_state={"i_l":0};other_token="hijkl"'
>>> dd = SimpleCookie()
>>> dd.load(token2)
>>> dd
<SimpleCookie: token='abcde'>

# without it
>>> token3 = 'token="abcde"'
>>> dd = SimpleCookie()
>>> dd.load(token3)
>>> dd
<SimpleCookie: token='abcde'>
```

So other cookies are still parsed as long as it's before the `g_state` cookie. Everything else after that are not parseable. Tried looking this issue up, and it seems theres an issue on http.cookies library on parsing curly bracket cookies ([source](https://bugs.python.org/issue25228)).

Anyone knows how to format the client request to prevent sending the cookie for `g_state` or at least find a way to not affect it on parsing all other tokens on the `Cookie` header? Like maybe rearranging the `g_state` cookie to always put the end?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround which is working for me: Javascript deleting the g_state cookie on all of the html pages.

```
<script>document.cookie = "g_state=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";</script>
```

Comment: The same approach can be used on single page applications before or after request which expects google login. I had this problem with aiohttp server which uses SimpleCookie as well

Answer (score 0):

This function will create a SimpleCookie object that process the g_state value ~

```
def get_cookies(cookie_str):
"""get_cookies: Get cookies from string"""
my_cookies = SimpleCookie()
dict_cookies = cookie_str.split("; ")
for item in dict_cookies:
    k, v = item.split("=", 1)
    my_cookies[k] = v

return my_cookies
```

Answer (score 0):

Known issue with python https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92936. Technically, it's not a legal cookie, so you'll have to work around it. The python bug report suggests a simple change to the http cookie pattern matcher as a generalized solution, or you can do your own parsing as suggested by others.